# dynamic programmin algorithm to find amount of numbers with n digits that divisible by 3

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Give a dynamic programming solution for the following problem. Given a number n>0, 
compute the number of natural numbers with n digits that are divisible by 3, and do not 
contain the digit "1".

Hint: The table will have size n×3

i breaking my head on this for a days cant find a sulotion.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you tried?  What were your ideas, intuition and approaches? Letting us know you were breaking your head for days doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic programming usually involves a recurrence relation that combines the solutions to smaller subproblems.

For your problem, note that for a number to be divisible by 3, its sum of digits must be divisible by 3. Let:

```
dp[i, s] = how many numbers with i digits have sum of digits s
```

We have:

```
dp[i, s] = dp[i - 1, s] +        <- use digit 0
           dp[i - 1, s - 2] +    <- use digit 2
           dp[i - 1, s - 3] +    <- use digit 3
           ...
           dp[i - 1, s - 9]      <- use digit 9
```

This can indeed by optimized to an `n x 3` table (it's now `n x S`) by working with the sum modulo `3`. That and the bases cases are left as an exercise or at least delayed until you show some work.

Comment: if i get it right, s is the finite sum, 1 to 9
for example 84 =  12 = 3 so s is 3?
 so, the base case is 
dp[1,1] = 1;
dp[1,2]=1;
.
.
.
dp[1,9]=1;

and the solution for the problem is sum of dp[i,3] dp[i,6] dp[i,9]

correct ?

Comment: @user3404096 - not exactly, `s` is the sum of the digits. For `84`, the sum of the digits is `12`, you do not compute the sum again. You also don't use `dp[1, 1]` because you said you can't use the digit 1, so `dp[1, 1] = 0`. The base case is correct for the others. The solution is not the sum of those it is the sum `dp[n, 0] + dp[n, 3] + dp[n, 6] + dp[n, 9] + dp[n, 12] + ... + dp[n, 3*k]`. To make it `n * 3`, you are correct in theory, although I haven't checked your formula. Make sure not to use the digit 1 and you're good to go.

Comment: and to make it n*3 i can use the modulo of 3 which can be 0,1 and 2
than dp[i,0] = dp[i-1,0] * 4 + dp[i-1,1] * 3 + dp[i,2] * 2 (its 2 cause i dont want to use the digit 1 which will laso make it devesible by 3) 
dp[i,1] = dp[i-1,0]*2 + dp[i-1, 1] *4 + dp[i-1.2] *3
dp[i,2] = dp[i-1,0]*3 + dp[i-1, 1] * 2 +dp[i-1,2]*4

correct ?